# c++ automake precompiled header support on centos

Tags: c++, automake, precompiled-headers

The background about this question is: my project(C++ language) contains too many files, which including boost, thrift, zookeeper, etc. Now the compilation duration takes too long.

As you know, Visual Studio supports precompiled headers, so as GCC. Because I use automake to manager the Make procedure, so What I want to ask for is whether automake supports precompiled headers? How can I write automake files if so?

Waiting and thranks for your answers.

Comment: Just use `ccache`. `.gch` approach is unreliable

Comment: Thanks @basin Does ccache support automake? I have read ccache help documents in its site, what I understand is that ccache only takes effect on previous built resulst, not the first time when you build the project, is it right?

Comment: `ccache` does not conflict with it, yes, it only good for when you recompile often.

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing is not about automake, but rather about writing makefiles.

Actually, you can try the [.gch](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html), but there're restrictons:

- write one common header to include everything (like `stdafx.h`)
- It should be the 1st include in all your sources
- use same `CFLAGS` to compile all your sources

It's a new functionality. You'd want to detect it in your `configure.ac`

Write a rule in your `Makefile.am`, name it like `stdafx.gch:`. Make it empty, if `gch` is not supported:

```
stdafx.gch: stdafx.h
    $(OPTIONAL_COMPILE_GCH)
.PHONY: $(OPTIONAL_STDAFX_GCH)
```

Make your `_OBJECTS` depend on `stdafx.gch`:

```
$(foo_SOURCES:.cpp=.$(OBJEXT)): stdafx.gch
# or (is it documented var?)
$(foo_OBJECTS)): stdafx.gch
```

Youc can use the documented [CXXCOMPILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Support.html) command to be sure that all CXXFLAGS are the same.

Detect in your `configure.ac`:

```
if ...; then
    [OPTIONAL_COMPILE_GCH='$(CXXCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $<']
    [OPTIONAL_STDAFX_GCH=]
else
    [OPTIONAL_COMPILE_GCH=]
    [OPTIONAL_STDAFX_GCH='stdafx.gch']
fi
AC_SUBST(OPTIONAL_COMPILE_GCH)
AC_SUBST(OPTIONAL_STDAFX_GCH)
```

## Update

You want your `.gch` to be recompiled, when any header file indirectly used by `stdafx.h` is modified.

Then you could add `stdafx.cpp` that does nothing, but includes `stdagx.h` and make `.gch` depend on `stdafx.o`. This way the dependency tracking would be managed by `automake`, but there's a problem:

`stdafx.o` itself could make use of `.gch` to compile faster, but if we add such dependency, it would be circular. It's not easy for me to find a solution.

Here's an example that uses status files to solve this: https://gist.github.com/basinilya/e00ea0055f74092b4790

Ideally, we would override the compilation command for `stdafx.o`, so it first creates `.gch` and then runs the standard automake compilation, but automake does not use `$(CXXCOMPILE)` as is. It creates a complex recipe from it (and it depends on automake version):

## Update 2

Another solution is to use gcc dependency tracking directly:

```
stdafx.h.gch: stdafx.h
    g++ -MT stdafx.h.gch -MD -MP -MF .deps/stdafx.Tpo -c -o stdafx.h.gch stdafx.h
    mv .deps/stdafx.Tpo .deps/stdafx.Po

-include .deps/stdafx.Po
```

By default, if precompiled header is used, `gcc -MD` will not put the list of header files into the generated dependencies file, just `.gch`. There's an option to fix this : `-fpch-deps` ([see bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28483)), but perhaps the default behavior is not that bad: if only the `.gch` depends on the headers, make will have less work to do.

Comment: Thanks @basin. My project's struct is just same as your description, and it can be built using VS2010(used precompiled-headers). I don't know how to implement precompiled-headers in automake or GCC.
Your solution is perfect, followings are my understanding:
1) generate precompiled-headers as gch-suffix obj files.
2) add the gch-suffix obj files into *_SOURCES.
3) then gcc will use precompiled-headers automaticly.
Would the *.gch be compiled automatically when some precompiled-headers changes?

Comment: It will make sense, if you have just one precompiled header. Include `boost` etc. in `stdafx.h`

Comment: > `Would the *.gch be compiled automatically when some precompiled-headers changes?` You can rely on `automake` dependencies tracking. Just add `stdafx.cpp` that does nothing, but includes `stdafx.h` (just like in VisualStudio). Then make the `gch` depend on `stdafx.$(OBJEXT)`. Don't add that `.cpp` to `_SOURCES` to avoid circular dependency

Comment: There's a problem with above: if `.gch` depends on `stdafx.o`, then `.gch` cannot be used to compile `stdafx.o`

Comment: As you said, The Makefile should be: stdafx.gch: stdafx.o
stdafx.o: stdafx.cpp
    $(CXXCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $<'
*_SOURCES = stdafx.gch This can solve the change-and-recompile problem, Thanks very much, You are very knowledgeable and professional. How should I translate this into automake? Do you have some advice on this?

Comment: Everything you put in `Makefile.am` will appear in `Makefile` (with some exceptions)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it!

Comment: I test the precompiled-headers solution, the result seems strange. using precompilded-header takes: real 5m52.302s
user 20m55.365s
sys 1m22.463s but not using precompiled-header takes real 4m48.445s
user 17m27.339s
sys 1m9.939s

Comment: @rolandrxw Check your dependencies files in `.deps/`. If they're big, gcc ignores your precompiled header

Comment: Thanks @basin. On your help I have implemented the precompiled-headers in automake. Following are the results: not using precompiled-headers:real 10m59.815s
user 35m59.854s
sys 2m43.815s using precompiled-headers:real 7m59.478s
user 21m23.465s
sys 2m4.518s